# Finding linear combinations of the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

What would be the easiest way to express the vectors of the canonical basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)\in \mathbb R ^3$ as a linear combinations of the vectors $v_1=(1,1,0), v_2=(-1,0,2),v_3=(1,1,1)$? And how can you find that? I've only managed to see that $e_3=v_3-v_1$.

Comment: Put $e_1=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ and solve for a, b and c. Same for $e_2$ and $e_3$.

Comment: You can solve the above equations “in bulk” by inverting a certain matrix.